# Define default settings for new sites on multisite network with mu-plugin

Tags: multisite

I have set up Wordpress with a multisite network. I have been searching around for hours and can't seem to find much documentation on setting custom defaults for all the new sites that are created on the network.

I am using a theme with a child theme installed.

Firstly I would like the default theme for all new sites created on the network to be my child-theme that is installed and Every new site starts with a basic default static front page.

Could this work or should i add it as a function in mu-plugin:

```
/** Sets default theme for new sites on network */
define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'theme-child');
```

Secondly, Every new site created I need to give access to all administrators on the network. Allowing them to work on all the sites automatically.

Should I try and create a mu-plugin if so please give some direction, or if there is a different way please advise. I haven't coded much in php. Please advise how this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out: I added the default theme in wp-config:

```
// Setting default theme for newly created sites 
define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'theme-child' );
```

for the static front page I added:

```
# ON SIGNUP OF NEW SITES A NEW PAGE IS CREATED CALLED "Homepage" AND SET AS 
THE STATIC FRONT PAGE

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'process_extra_field_on_blog_signup', 10, 6 );

function process_extra_field_on_blog_signup( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, 
$path, $site_id, $meta ) {
switch_to_blog($blog_id);


$new_page_title = 'Homepage'; //page title
$new_page_content = 'TEST'; //content of page goes here
$new_page_template = ''; //page template.

$page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
$new_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page', 
        'post_title' => $new_page_title,
        'post_content' => $new_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
);
if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
        if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
        }
}

$homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Homepage' );
if ( $homepage )
{
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
restore_current_blog();
}
```

Now I just need to make all users administrators on newly created sites.

Comment: Did you add both of these to the wp-config.php file?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goals in a WordPress multisite network, you can indeed use a combination of the `wp-config.php` file and a custom plugin `mu-plugin`. please follow a step-by-step guide below the scenario.

**1. Set Default Theme for New Sites**

Add the following line to your `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-child-theme-folder-name');
```

Replace 'your-child-theme-folder-name' with the actual folder name of your child theme.

**2. Set Default Static Front Page for New Sites**

To set a default static front page for all new sites, you can use a mu-plugin. Create a new PHP file `e.g. custom-defaults.php` and place it in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory. If the mu-plugins directory doesn't exist, you can create it.

Inside `custom-defaults.php`, add the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * Set default static front page for new sites in a multisite network.
 */
function set_default_front_page() {
    update_site_option('site_front_page', 'your-static-front-page-id');
    update_site_option('site_posts_page', 'your-blog-posts-page-id');
}
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'set_default_front_page');
```

Replace 'your-static-front-page-id' and 'your-blog-posts-page-id' with the actual page IDs for your static front page and blog posts page.

**3. Grant Access to All Administrators**

For granting access to all administrators on the network, you can use a mu-plugin as well. Create another PHP file e.g. `grant-admin-access.php` in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory.

Inside `grant-admin-access.php`, add the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * Grant access to all administrators on the network.
 */
function grant_admin_access_to_all_sites($user_id, $password, $meta) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $user->for_each_blog(function ($blog_id) use ($user_id) {
        grant_super_admin($user_id);
    });
}
add_action('wpmu_new_user', 'grant_admin_access_to_all_sites', 10, 3);
```

This code uses the `grant_super_admin()` function to give super admin privileges to a user on all sites in the network.